# Increase the amount of data on listview when the data is successfully stored in sqlite in uwp

Tags: c#, sqlite, listview, uwp

I have a listview whose data comes from a sqlite database. The database is created when the user selects the list on the previous page whose data comes from JSON.
Code:

```
ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
            if (connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
            {
                loading.IsIndeterminate = true;

                try
                {
                    string urlPath = "https://.../tryout_perid";
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

                    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("tid", ((App)(App.Current)).ID)
                    };

                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        loading.IsIndeterminate = false;
                        RequestException();
                    }
                    string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                    JsonArray jsonData = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();

                    foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonData)
                    {
                        JsonObject groupObject2 = groupValue1.GetObject();
                        string id = groupObject2["id"].GetString();
                        string title = groupObject2["judul"].GetString();

                        QuizHome quiz = new QuizHome();
                        quiz.ID = id;
                        ((App)(App.Current)).ID = quiz.ID.ToString();
                        quiz.Title = title;
                        quizDataSource.Add(quiz);

                        if (quizDataSource.Count > 0)
                        {
                            string InsertQuiz = @"INSERT INTO DBName (ID,Judul) SELECT '" + id.ToString() + "','" + title.ToString() + "','" + "' WHERE not exists " +
                                "(select ID and Judul FROM DBName WHERE ID='" + id.ToString() + "' and Judul='" + title.ToString() + "')";
                            var quizName = objConn.Prepare(InsertQuiz);
                            quizName.Step();
                        }

                        JsonArray jsonDataSoal = groupObject2["list_soal"].GetArray();
                        foreach (JsonValue groupValueSoal in jsonDataSoal)
                        {
                            JsonObject groupObjectSoal = groupValueSoal.GetObject();

                            string qid = groupObjectSoal["qid"].GetString();
                            string pertanyaan = groupObjectSoal["question"].GetString();

                            QuizQuestion question = new QuizQuestion();
                            question.QID = qid;
                            question.Pertanyaan = pertanyaan;
                            questionDataSource.Add(question);

                            if (questionDataSource.Count > 0)
                            {
                                string InsertQuestion = @"INSERT INTO DBQuestion (QID,Pertanyaan) SELECT '" + qid.ToString() + "','" + pertanyaan.ToString() + "' WHERE not exists " +
                                    "(select QID and Pertanyaan FROM DBQuestion WHERE OID='" + qid.ToString() + "' and Pertanyaan='" + pertanyaan.ToString() + "')";
                                var quizQuestion = objConn.Prepare(InsertQuestion);
                                quizQuestion.Step();
                            }

                            JsonArray jsonDataOption = groupObjectSoal["jawaban"].GetArray();
                            foreach (JsonValue groupValueOption in jsonDataOption)
                            {
                                JsonObject groupObjectOption = groupValueOption.GetObject();

                                string oid = groupObjectOption["oid"].GetString();
                                string option = groupObjectOption["q_option"].GetString();
                                string score = groupObjectOption["score"].GetString();

                                QuizOption pilihan = new QuizOption();
                                pilihan.OID = oid;
                                pilihan.Option = option;
                                optionDataSource.Add(pilihan);

                                if (optionDataSource.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    string InsertOption = @"INSERT INTO DBOption (OID,Option) SELECT '" + oid.ToString() + "','" + option.ToString() + "','" + "' WHERE not exists " +
                                        "(select OID and Option FROM DBOption WHERE OID='" + oid.ToString() + "' and Option='" + option.ToString() + "')";
                                    var quizOption = objConn.Prepare(InsertOption);
                                    quizOption.Step();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        this.Loaded += ReadTryoutList_Loaded;
                        loading.IsIndeterminate = false;
                    }
                }

private void ReadTryoutList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReadAllDBName dbName = new ReadAllDBName();
            DB_TryoutList = dbName.GetAllDBName();
            ListTryout.ItemsSource = DB_TryoutList.OrderByDescending(i => i.ID).ToList();//Binding DB data to LISTBOX and Latest contact ID can Display first.  
            if (DB_TryoutList.Count == 0)
            {
                statuskosongStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                ListTryout.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                statuskosongStack.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                ListTryout.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
```

I am having problems, that is when the user selects the list on the previous page and the data is successfully stored in the database, but the amount of data on listview is not increased. If I click the back button and enter on this page again, then the data on listview increases. How do I get listview to increase in the number of data when the data is successfully saved?

Comment: Could you try to load the data and assign the `ListTryout.ItemsSource` to the data again on the new page's `OnNavigatedTo` method? If it still has this issue, a simple reproduce sample will be better to troubleshoot it.

Comment: @Breeze Sorry for delay respond. Here the sample of the project: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Assf-w0FVKyxgQM0acVWm5WvPXJe The problem in TryoutLibrary1 Page

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the asynchronous method in your code. After you click the item, you navigate to the `TryoutLibrary1` page. On this page, you save the data to the database meanwhile you get the data source from the database on the `Page.Loaded` event. But when you get the data, the clicked item has not been insert into the database, so it will not display on the page until you reload the data(reenter the page again).

So you should reconsider your logic again in the `ItemClick` event, you should make sure the data have saved into the database then you get and set the data as the `ListView.ItemsSource`. As a example, when you click the item, you can create a object and put it into a local `ObservableCollection` object, then set the `ObservableCollection` as the ListView itemsSource to make it display on the UI, on other side, you save the item to the database.